# MYSQLdb/Python - not all arguments converted during string formatting error?

Tags: python, mysql, string, mysql-python

Trying to select some info from a database, I have a database manager class that looks like this:

```
class DatabaseManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", 
                     user="neal", 
                      passwd="hacker123",
                      db="massive") 

        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
```

When trying to do a SELECT like this:

```
    db = DatabaseManager()
    db.cursor.execute("SELECT password FROM USERS WHERE apikey = %s", str(request.apikey))
```

I get a

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

This is odd as I have similar queries elsewhere that worked fine, like this one:

```
db.cursor.execute('''INSERT into USERS(email, username, password, apikey) values (%s, %s, %s, %s)''',
    (request.email, request.username, request.password, apikey))
```

Am I doing this wrong?

EDIT: Column confusion, table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
username varchar(25) NOT NULL,
password varchar(25) NOT NULL,
apikey varchar(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
UNIQUE(email),
UNIQUE(username),
UNIQUE(apikey)
);
```

Comment: Did you try passing the argument as a tu9le with a single string?

Answer (score 1):

That is because the [second argument of execute is an iterable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html). So you would be better off with a list, set, or tuple.

Try this:

```
db.cursor.execute("SELECT password FROM USERS WHERE apikey = %s", (str(request.apikey),))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should give tuple, no need to parse str;

```
db.cursor.execute("SELECT password FROM USERS WHERE apikey = %s", (request.apikey,))
```

Answer (score -1):

you are much better off with something like this:

db.cursor.execute("SELECT password FROM USERS WHERE apikey = {0}".format(str(request.apikey)))

given that request.apikey can be implicitly converted into a string

Comment: When I do this, I get this error: ```File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'a443160d' in 'where clause'")```.  The API key is in the format ```a443160d-66fb-482c-953b-af1349b9c5ba```, and the column is named apikey. Why does it think the value I'm passing it is the name of the column?

Comment: if apikey value is a string, then include quotations('). If its a integer it should be fine